# Is \usepackage{xcolor} clash with package \usepackage{hhline, boldline}?

Tags: option-clash

I have an error here, cannot find what is the reason,

[image]

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)that produces the error messages you get.

Comment: As you can see from `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline,boldline}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}`, The combination of `\usepackage{xcolor}` with `\usepackage{hhline,boldline}` will not result in any error message. The reason for the error message you showd must be somewhere else.

Comment: @leandriis. Thanks. I tried to check back my history in Overleaf. I added in `\usepackage{pdfpages}` making this error. But the whole  list a lot

Comment: Do you load the `xcolor` package in your preamble twice? From the error message you showed, it seems as if you tries to use `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}` which will indeed result in the shown "option clash" error message. If yo, please make sure, you only load packages once.

Comment: @aan - So far, you've posted about 200 queries on this site. I believe you should have become aware in the meantime that posting a screenshot of some error message is *not sufficient* to allow folks to come up with an accurate diagnosis of the problem, let along provide a cure. Please start posting [minimum working examples](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that give rise to the problems you wish to fix. Otherwise, far too much time is wasted on needlessly trying to guess what may or may not be going on.

Comment: the image that you have posted contains a suggested fix that usually works, did you try that?

Comment: The error happens when TeX has processed the instruction `\usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor}` and is about to read `\usepackage{hhline,boldline}` (which has nothing to do with the error). There is another package, loaded earlier, which also loads `xcolor` (without options): find it and move it *after* `\usepackage{svgnames,table]{xcolor}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information from the screenshot and from your comments, I guess, you used something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

This will result in the below error message which you also showed in your question.

```
The package xcolor has already been loaded with options:
  []
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [table,svgnames]
Adding the global options:
  ,table,svgnames
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
```

Following the advice from the error message, you can use the following example with `table` and `svgnames` added a s global options:

```
\documentclass[table,svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Changing the loading order is sufficient.

Comment: @leandriis, you are correct. Adding ` \documentclass[12pt,oneside,svgnames,table]{book}` works well